How do I copy code from a main branch to a another repository's main branch
I have a main branch from REPO1 and want to copy the code to the main branch from REPO2 without the history, commit message or anything else.
I tried to mirroring the repository but got all commits, history and branches too.
How do I do this?

Do you want to keep the history of repo2? It's not clear from your question. What prevents you from simply copying the files?

...inexperience

If, as you said, you don't care about keeping history (no commits messages, no previous branches etc) you can simply delete the git directory:
cd <path_to_your_project>
rm -rf .git

then create a new one using  git init.
You will then be able to set a new upstream branch (using git remote add origin <your_new_branch>)

git remote add remote_repo <repo_url>
git pull remote_repo master --depth 1

Then you can change a single commit, like this:
git commit --amend --author="John Doe <johndoe@address.com>" -m"Initial commit"

